# Paaing multiple parameters to this function?

Tags: autohotkey

I have been messing with this amazing function I found on the old forums. There is not much information on it.

I tried to figure it out on my own but to no avail. I could really use some help with. [Here](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/30323-wingetall-get-all-windows-titleclasspidprocess-name/) is the link to it.

So far I can only seem to pass one parameter to it, but reading his brief description it seems possible to pass multiple parameters to it. If I am mistaken please let me know.

I would like to invoke the function like this `WinGetAll("Title", Class', 'Hwnd', 'Process', 'PID')` , so that it will return all the properties of a window per  line:

```
[Window #1 Title],[Window #1 Class], [Window #1 Hwn], [Window #1 Process], [Window #1 PID]
[Window #2 Title],[Window #2 Class], [Window #2 Hwn], [Window #2 Process], [Window #2 PID]
[Window #3 Title],[Window #3 Class], [Window #3 Hwn], [Window #3 Process], [Window #3 PID]
<etc etc >
```

With my experimentations, I was only able to use two parameters at once:

```
WinTitles := WinGetAll("Title", "On")
WinTitles := WinGetAll("Title", "Off")
```

I am very new to AHK, There may be much better solutions. If so please let me know.
I just need a reliabe way to get every window and its properties listed in a single line:

```
[Window #1 Title],[Window #1 Class], [Window #1 Hwn], [Window #1 Process], [Window #1 PID]
```

With the option to hide system windows such as svchost.exe / csrss.exe / services.exe etc

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
WinGet, id, list
Loop, %id%
{
    this_ID := id%A_Index%
    WinGet, exStyle, exStyle, ahk_id %this_ID%
    If !(exStyle & 0x100)
        continue
    WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %this_ID%
    If (title = "")
        continue    
    WinGetClass, class, ahk_id %this_ID%
    WinGet, PID, PID, ahk_id %this_ID%
    WinGet, ProcessName, ProcessName, ahk_id %this_ID%
    Index++
    wins .= "Window #" Index . ":`ntitle = "  title "`n"  "class ="  class "`n"  "hwnd ="  this_ID  "`n"    "PID ="  PID  "`n"  "ProcessName ="  ProcessName "`n`n"
}
MsgBox, % wins
```